# How to prevent the display of next page screen until first page request success won't come in angular material stepper

Tags: angular

I have a login form which is based on mobile number and an OTP. I want to create something like gmail login. for that, I am using angular material stepper but in the stepper, if next button will be clicked then it will go to the next screen however I do not want to go to the next screen until the success message and OTP from API do not come. 
Is it possible to achieve using angular?

```js
export class StepperOverviewExample {
  isLinear = true;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  next() {
console.log(this.firstFormGroup.value);
// here I will call my service and get the response

  }
}
```

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter Mobile Number</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="tel" placeholder="mobile" formControlName="firstCtrl"  required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext (click)="next()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <p>We have sent a text message to the given number </p>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter OTP</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="OTP" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: hey you can disable button till your response come from the server. as you can add a variable make it false and once response comes make it true and pass that variable to next button

Comment: hi @HrishikeshKale, if I will disable the next button then how will I be able to call the method which will call the service?

Comment: studying your case if the user puts their number and till opt comes you can disable the next button. if I am not wrong, you can call a service on onblur method or you can give validate phone number button if the user clicked on that button show your otp field and next button on server response.

Comment: You could take a look at angular's route resolvers. If you're using routes to move from a screen to another, using resolvers will not display your component until you get the data you need. Here is a nice tutorial: https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Comment: Did you solve this? I'd need to prevent going back until service has responded.